# Use pandas.read_csv to read files containing str() in file's name

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to use pandas.read_csv to read files that contain the date in their names. I used the below code to do the job. The problem is that the files name is not consistent as the number of date change the pattern. I was wondering if there is a way to let the code read the file with parts of the name is the date in front of the file name?

[image]

```
for x in range(0,10):
dat = 20170401+x
dat2 = dat+15
file_name='JS_ALL_V.'+str(dat)+'_'+str(dat2)+'.csvp.gzip'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,compression='gzip',delimiter='|')
```

Comment: Can you read file names using  "names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('/your_path')]" , now pass file name one by one in pd.read_csv

Comment: @Vipin it seems like glob.glob('*.csvp.gzip') is not working. the file type maybe not supported

Comment: what is the error, please provide your code snippet and error.

Comment: @Vipin It is all good now. I just made some typo in my code. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob library to read file names in unix style

Below is its hello world:

```
import glob
for name in glob.glob('dir/*'):
    print name
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative of using glob.glob() (since it seems not working) is [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) in order to have a list containing all the elements (or just the files) in your path.